# Does the Oracle NoSQL Database SQL query support slice for an array?

Tags: nosql, oracle-nosql

One of our applications stores a number of arrays in a table. We need to query these arrays in many different ways.

Does the Oracle NoSQL Database SQL query support the following?

Simple examples:

Let's assume the following is part of the table myTable:

```
myarray array(integer)
```

We need to implement the following queries:

```
SELECT username, myarray[1] AS t FROM myTable

SELECT username, [myarray[0:2]] AS t FROM myTable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, both queries are supported.